# Antenna tuning of 2.4GHz WiFi board

Tags: rf, antenna, esp32, impedance-matching, wifi

I am new to the RF electronics and tuning of antennas.  I am working on a 2.4GHz Wi-Fi board design using an [ESP32-S2](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/socs/esp32-s2) chip. The board consists of a 50 ohm single ended impedance trace for the antenna with PI network. The PCB was designed according to [JLC7628 Stackup](https://cart.jlcpcb.com/impedance) with 0.8 mm PCB thickness and 4-layers. I kept the antenna trace width to 0.3493 mm according to their impedance calculator. I had also verified trace width calculation with KiCad's calculator tools. The PCB was also manufactured from [JLCPCB](https://jlcpcb.com/).

I am trying to measure the resonant frequency of the board using a [NanoVNA V2 Plus4](https://nanorfe.com/nanovna-v2.html). Right now only a 0 ohm jumper is mounted and I am using Johanson Technology's [2450AT18B100E](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/johanson-technology-inc/2450AT18B0100001E/1560677) as chip antenna.

The 1st layer is signal layer:

[image: 1st layer - signal layer]

The 2nd layer contains GND plane with no traces:

[image: 2nd layer - GND layer]

The result from NanoVNA is as follows:

[image]

1. Is the resonant frequency of the antenna at 2.74129GHz as marked in the above image?
2. Do you think this board can be tunned to get optimal performance for 2.4GHz Wi-Fi, or do I need to modify and re-spin the board?
3. Do you see any problems with the board design?